# set font with different style in swift in complete project from 1place

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I want to set the font for buttons , uilabels etc in complete project but with different property.

for eg :
uilabel for header or title will be font size : 20 with font family : helvetica

uilablel font for subtitle will be font size : 16 with font family : airel etc

I know below thing.But this set uilabel for my complete project with same font size and font family.
I wanted to set 4 different category of font which i can implement through out the application via storyboard.
so i change in one place and it get reflected it whole project.

```
 [[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFontName" size:17.0]];
```

Comment: Why not use `UIFont preferredFont(forTextStyle:)`? Then you get the correct font based on the user's text and accessibility settings and not some hardcoded font you choose.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you for quick reply. I want to manage font style for complete project from app delegate

Comment: Why does the title mention Swift but the code in the question is Objective-C?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the answer :

```
struct AppFontName {
    static let regular = "Helvetica"
    static let bold = "CourierNewPS-BoldMT"
    static let italic = "CourierNewPS-ItalicMT"
}

extension UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName {
    static let nsctFontUIUsage = UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName(rawValue: "NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute")
}

extension UIFont {

    @objc class func mySystemFont(ofSize size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: AppFontName.regular, size: size)!
    }

    @objc class func myBoldSystemFont(ofSize size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: AppFontName.bold, size: size)!
    }

    @objc class func myItalicSystemFont(ofSize size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: AppFontName.italic, size: size)!
    }

    @objc convenience init(myCoder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        guard
            let fontDescriptor = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "UIFontDescriptor") as? UIFontDescriptor,
            let fontAttribute = fontDescriptor.fontAttributes[.nsctFontUIUsage] as? String else {
                self.init(myCoder: aDecoder)
                return
        }
        var fontName = ""
        switch fontAttribute {
        case "CTFontRegularUsage":
            fontName = AppFontName.regular
        case "CTFontEmphasizedUsage", "CTFontBoldUsage":
            fontName = AppFontName.bold
        case "CTFontObliqueUsage":
            fontName = AppFontName.italic
        default:
            fontName = AppFontName.regular
        }
        self.init(name: fontName, size: fontDescriptor.pointSize)!
    }

    class func overrideInitialize() {
        guard self == UIFont.self else { return }

        if let systemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(systemFont(ofSize:))),
            let mySystemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(mySystemFont(ofSize:))) {
            method_exchangeImplementations(systemFontMethod, mySystemFontMethod)
        }

        if let boldSystemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(boldSystemFont(ofSize:))),
            let myBoldSystemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(myBoldSystemFont(ofSize:))) {
            method_exchangeImplementations(boldSystemFontMethod, myBoldSystemFontMethod)
        }

        if let italicSystemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(italicSystemFont(ofSize:))),
            let myItalicSystemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(myItalicSystemFont(ofSize:))) {
            method_exchangeImplementations(italicSystemFontMethod, myItalicSystemFontMethod)
        }

        if let initCoderMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(UIFontDescriptor.init(coder:))), // Trick to get over the lack of UIFont.init(coder:))
            let myInitCoderMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(UIFont.init(myCoder:))) {
            method_exchangeImplementations(initCoderMethod, myInitCoderMethod)
        }
    }
}


@UIApplicationMain


class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        UIFont.overrideInitialize()
return true
      }
```